# Как проверить вышел ли курсор за предел блока. Событие mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css, веб-программирование, handlers

С помощью mouseover сделал что при наведении на нужный блок он добовлял класс к обьекту. Но как мне проверить находиться ли курсор в поле обьекта и если его там нету то выполнить действие?

```js
var ShearCardOver = document.querySelectorAll(".shares-card-holder").forEach(e=>{
    e.addEventListener("mouseover",e=>{
        var CardHolderTarget = e.currentTarget.dataset.path;
        document.querySelectorAll(".card-btn").forEach(e=>{
            if (!document.querySelector(`[data-target=${CardHolderTarget}]`).classList.contains("open")) {
                document.querySelector(`[data-target=${CardHolderTarget}]`).classList.add("card-btn-hover");
                document.querySelector(`[data-target=${CardHolderTarget}]`).classList.add("open");
    
            }
        })
    })
})
```

Comment: можете добавить пример вашего кода к вопросу?

Comment: изменил добавив код джс

Comment: а добавить `html` и `css` можете добавить?

Comment: `e.target.getBoundingClientRect()` и дальше смотрите по размерам блока и координатам находится ли курсор в блоке.

Comment: Всем спасибо,решил